# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors in unity 2019.4.11f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make some ar and i was watching the videos on youtube how to do that and i followed along.But at last it showed me some errors.

I am putting some screenshot so that you can tell what's wrong  i am doing...
Thanks in advance for helping me..

[image]

[image]

[image]

THESE ARE THE PACKAGES THAT I HAVE INSTALLED IN FOR THIS AR

1. AR FOUNDATION - 2.1.10
   2 AR CORE -2.1.12
   3 AR KIT - 2.1.10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Build .APK in Unity 2019.2.4f1 with ARcore : Manifest Merger failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188332/cannot-build-apk-in-unity-2019-2-4f1-with-arcore-manifest-merger-failed)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems with this Unity version too. I found no fix for this Unity version, but I tried the `2020.1.10f1` version and there it all worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: hey if you learned from youtube can you share the link so that i could also lean it..

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem as well. Android APK compiles fine before adding AR packages. Added AR Foundation 2.1.10, AR Subsystems 2.1.3 and ARCore XR Plugin 2.1.12 (All 2019.4 verified). Android API set to 24, Vulkan removed, but fails at this point.

[Build Failure Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOZ5.png)

Turns out that it's an issue with Gradle, you need to use Gradle 5.6.4 and follow the instructions here for Unity 2019.4 https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/android-11-build